# Error when Parsing Nested JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am facing an "Error parsing data" error when parsing my JSON file

When parsing the following text the parser seems to work for these:

```
{"vid":"2",
"uid":"1",
"title":"BangsarSouth",
"log":"",
"status":"1",
"comment":"1",
"promote":"0",
"sticky":"0",
"nid":"2",
"type":"property",
"language":"und",
"created":"1369825923",
"changed":"1370534102",
"tnid":"0"
```

but once it reaches this part of the file, it breaks down and gives me a parsing error

`"body":{"und":[{"value":"Some description for Bangsar South.\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.","summary":"","format":"filtered_html","safe_value":"<p>Some description for Bangsar South.<br />\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam` etc ...

I suspect that the error is due to the nested elements. could anyone suggest a solution for my problem?

Below is my javacode

```
try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://xxxxxx.com/rest/node/2.json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    try {           
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
        Log.e("faridi",result);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }


    //parse json data
    try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: please provide the complete json

Comment: please make sure {"body":{"und":[{"value":"Some.."},{"value":"Someother"} ]}} and so on always use [jsonLint](http://jsonlint.com) to verify json

Comment: The problem is that you have a nested `JSON Array` and you need to pull that array and parse it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson and Spring are will be your friend.

You can use Spring's RestTemplate library and which uses jackson for all the heavy JSON work.

For sanity's sake, lets say this is the JSON response coming back.

```
{
    "message" : "Hello World",
    "answer" : "42"
}
```

Now first thing you do is to "deserialize" into a Pojo.  Do a bit of googling for Java Jackson deserialize and you should be good to go.

If you ever used JAXB to unmarshall xml before, you'll be right at home.  Its super easy, just make a Pojo container of the Json response.

```
@JsonSerialize
public class JsonResponse {
    private String message;
    private int answer;
    // Getters and seters below.
}
```

Then all you have to RestTemplate make the Json Rest call and make the JsonResponse object for you.

Since, you are only doing an HTTP GET method, this is the simplest approach.

```
RestTemplate restTempalte = new RestTemplate();
JsonResponse jsonResponse = restTemplate.getForObject("url", JsonResponse.class);
```

Besides being a simple one liner, it's easy to mock REST responses for unit tests as well.

If you want any data about the transmission, use getForEntity().